# Enlazar Click de tarjeta de QToolBox con QLineEdit en un QFrame -- No se detecta el padre

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, signals

Estoy desarrollando una app que simula un POS (Punto de venta por su siglas en inglés).
La estructura del proyecto contiene una ventana principal la cual aloja en sí un QStackedlayout en el que
se guardan las ventanas de la aplicación. Una de las paginas o ventanas de la aplicación (Ver la imagen), la más importante, está constituida por un QToolBox que contiene las categorías de productos a despachar y un QFrame, en este último se incrustaron algunos QLineEdits a fin de poblarlos con la información de determinada tarjeta al ser clickeada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La tarjeta y los otros widgets fueron desarrollados en QDesigner y posteriormente se les realizó algunas modificaciones personales. Esta tarjeta es la plantilla o clase que se instanciará en cada pagina (o QWidget) del QToolBox según su categoría. Es decir, según el numero de productos por categoría, así será el numero de tarjetas por pagina en el QToolBox.
La situación problema es que necesito que cada una de las tarjetas sean estilo botón, de modo que pueda clicarlas y así poblar los QLineEdits del QFrame Adjunto el código de la tarjeta que en realidad se llama topcone_cad.py
Código de la tarjeta

```
from qt_core import *
```

`from model.producto import Producto`

```
class TopCone(QWidget):

    prodClicked = pyqtSignal(Producto)
    def __init__(self,prod: Producto, parent=None):
        super(TopCone, self).__init__()
        self.item=prod
        self.parent=parent
        self.setObjectName("TopCone")
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 100))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(200, 100))
        self.setStyleSheet("#TopCone{border-radius:6px;}")
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(2)
        self.main_layout.setObjectName("main_layout")
        #self.main_frame = QFrameClickable(self)
        self.main_frame = QFrame(self)
        self.main_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.Panel)
        self.main_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.main_frame.setObjectName("main_frame")
        self.main_frame.setStyleSheet(f"""
            #main_frame{{
                border-radius:4px;
                border:2px solid #385723;
                background-color: #FFF7E1;
            }}
            #main_frame:hover{{
                border:4px solid #385723;
                background-color: #FFF2CC;
            }}
        """)
        self.card_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.main_frame)
        self.card_layout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
        self.card_layout.setSpacing(2)
        self.card_layout.setObjectName("card_layout")
        self.pxConeImg = QLabel(parent=self.main_frame)
        self.pxConeImg.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 79))
        self.pxConeImg.setMaximumSize(QSize(70, 79))
        self.pxConeImg.setScaledContents(True)
        self.pxConeImg.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.pxConeImg.setObjectName("pxConeImg")
        self.pxConeImg.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        self.card_layout.addWidget(self.pxConeImg)
        final= self.item.Codigo[2:]
        match final:
            case '11'|'12'|'13':
                self.pxConeImg.setPixmap(QPixmap(AppConfig().PosIcon('11')))
            case '21' | '22' | '23':
               self.pxConeImg.setPixmap(QPixmap(AppConfig().PosIcon('12')))
            case _:
                self.pxConeImg.setPixmap(QPixmap(AppConfig().PosIcon('13')))
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(9)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.txtTopConeName = QLabel(parent=self.main_frame)
        self.txtTopConeName.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 60))
        self.txtTopConeName.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 60))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.txtTopConeName.setFont(font)
        self.txtTopConeName.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 85, 0);background-color:transparent")
        self.txtTopConeName.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.txtTopConeName.setWordWrap(True)
        self.txtTopConeName.setObjectName("txtTopConeName")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.txtTopConeName)
        self.txtTopConePrice = QLabel(parent=self.main_frame)
        self.txtTopConePrice.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 30))
        self.txtTopConePrice.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 30))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.txtTopConePrice.setFont(font)
        self.txtTopConePrice.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.txtTopConePrice.setWordWrap(True)
        self.txtTopConePrice.setObjectName("txtTopConePrice")
        self.txtTopConePrice.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent; color:rgb(0,0,88);")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.txtTopConePrice)
        self.card_layout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.main_frame)

        self.txtTopConeName.setText(self.item.Nombre)
        self.txtTopConePrice.setText(f"$ {int(self.item.Precio)}")
        if self.item.ProdImage is not None:
            foto =QPixmap()
            foto.loadFromData(self.item.ProdImage, "PNG", Qt.AutoColor)
            self.pxConeImg.setPixmap(foto)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
    

    def enterEvent(self, event: QEnterEvent) -> None:
        self.txtTopConeName.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);background-color:transparent")

    def leaveEvent(self, a0: QEvent) -> None:
       self.txtTopConeName.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 85, 0);background-color:transparent")
     
    def mousePressEvent(self, a0: QMouseEvent | None) -> None:
        self.main_frame.setStyleSheet(f"""
            #main_frame{{
                border:3px solid #F8C10C; 
                background-color: #003300;
                color:#FFF7E1;
            }}
        """)
        self.txtTopConeName.setStyleSheet("color:#FFF7E1;background-color:transparent")
        self.prodClicked.emit(self.item)
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, a0: QMouseEvent | None) -> None:
        self.main_frame.setStyleSheet(f"""
            #main_frame{{
                border-radius:4px;
                border:2px solid #385723;
                background-color: #FFF7E1;
            }}
            #main_frame:hover{{
                border:4px solid #385723;
                background-color: #FFF2CC;
            }}
        """)
        self.txtTopConeName.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 85, 0);background-color:transparent")

Finalmente adjunto el código del controlador donde se cargan variables y obviamente la vista...

    from qt_core import *
from view.pages.page_pos import Ui_Form
from model.producto import Producto
from model.item import Item
from model.dbman import DbMan
from view.widgets.card_tile import DipTile
from view.widgets.topcone_card import TopCone
from model.factura import Factura

class PosCtrl(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(PosCtrl, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # Variables de clase
        self.NroFactura=""
        self.tipoServicio="ConsES"

        #
        self.ui.btnEditRow.clicked.connect(self.cargarItem)
        self.ui.rbtnDelivery.clicked.connect(lambda: self.asignarServicio('domicilio'))
        self.ui.rbtnInPlace.clicked.connect(lambda: self.asignarServicio("en_sitio"))
        self.ui.rbtnCarryHome.clicked.connect(lambda: self.asignarServicio("llevar"))
        #
        self.lista_conos: Producto =list()
        self.lista_toppings=list()
        self.lista_bebidas=list()
        self.lista_salsas=list()
        self.pedido_actual:Item=list()  
        self.factura = Factura()

        self.load_conos()
        self.load_salsas()
       
    def asignarServicio(self, val):
        match val:
            case 'domicilio':
                #activateClientAddress(True)
                self.tipoServicio="ConsAD"
            case 'en_sitio':
                self.tipoServicio="ConsES"
            case 'llevar':
                self.tipoServicio="ConsAS"

    
    @pyqtSlot(Producto)
    def load_item_from_display(self, p:Producto):
        
        self.ui.txtInvoiceDetail = p.Nombre
        self.ui.txtInvoiceUnitPrice= p.Precio
        self.ui.txtInvoiceProdCode= p.Codigo

    def cargarItem(self):
        print("Me estoy cargando los items")


        
#Metodo para quitar las tarjetas del grid del scrollarea
    def setTileContainerEmpty(self):
        for i in reversed(range(self.tileBox.count())): 
            widgetToRemove = self.tileBox.itemAt(i).widget()
            # remove it from the layout list
            self.tileBox.removeWidget(widgetToRemove)
            # remove it from the gui
            widgetToRemove.setParent(None)

    def load_conos(self):
        
        self.lista_conos.clear()
        self.lista_conos    =  DbMan().cargarProductosxCategoria('conos')
        pos=list()
        cant=len(self.lista_conos)
        if cant>0:
            pos=self.posItems(cant, 3)        
            for xp in range(cant):
               xItem=self.lista_conos[xp]
               cono = TopCone(xItem)
               self.ui.layout_conos.addWidget(cono,pos[xp].x, pos[xp].y)
        else:
            pass

        
    # def load_toppings(self):
    #     self.lista_toppings.clear()
    #     categoria= "toppings"
    #     self.lista_conos = DbMan().cargarListaProductos(categoria)
    #     pos=list()
    #     cant=len(self.lista_toppings)
    #     if cant>0:
    #         pos=self.posItems(cant, 4)        
    #         for xp in range(cant):
    #             tarjeta = QItemTile(self.lista_productos[xp],self)
    #             self.tileBox.addWidget(tarjeta,pos[xp].x, pos[xp].y)
    #         self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.tileContainer)
    #     else:
    #        pass

    # def load_bebidas(self):
    #     self.lista_conos.clear()
    #     categoria= "conos"
    #     self.lista_conos = DbMan().cargarListaProductos(categoria)
    #     pos=list()
    #     cant=len(self.lista_conos)
    #     if cant>0:
    #         pos=self.posItems(cant, 4)        
    #         for xp in range(cant):
    #             tarjeta = QItemTile(self.lista_productos[xp],self)
    #             self.tileBox.addWidget(tarjeta,pos[xp].x, pos[xp].y)
    #         self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.tileContainer)
    #     else:
    #         if self.cbxTiendaCategorias.currentText()!="Seleccione una categoría" or self.cbxTiendaCategorias.currentText()!="No hay categorías disponibles":
    #             pass #MsgBox().iMsg("Carga de Productos para Salida","No existen productos disponibles en esta categoría",2)

    def load_salsas(self):
        self.lista_salsas.clear()
        self.lista_salsas = DbMan().cargarProductosxCategoria('salsas')
        cant=len(self.lista_salsas)
        
        if cant>0:
            pos=list()
            pos=self.posItems(cant, 4)        
            for xp in range(cant):
                gravy = self.lista_salsas[xp]
                dip = DipTile(gravy,self)
                self.ui.layout_salsas.addWidget(dip,pos[xp].x, pos[xp].y)
        else:
            pass 
    
 
    def posItems(self, cant, cols=4):        
        col=cols
        fil=cant//col
        nPos=[CardPosition(x,y) for x in range(fil) for y in range(col)]
        if cant%col!=0:
            nPos.extend([CardPosition(fil, k) for k in range(cant%col)])
        return nPos


class CardPosition:
    def __init__(self,x=0, y=0):
        self.__x=x
        self.__y=y

    @property
    def x(self):    return self.__x

    @property
    def y(self):    return self.__y
```

Como pueden ver, incluí en la tarjeta en código para emitir la señal de que se ha hecho click a fin que se pueda conectar algun elemento (Quizá la misma tajeta) con esta señal y poder pasar los datos al QFrame. y poder continuar el código. Es en realidad en lo que estoy estancado. Así mismo adjunto el código de la ventana (o página) que contiene el QToolBox y el QFrame y el codigo del controlador.

He tratado de hacerlo buscando al padre de la ventana que contiene los widgets qtoolbox y qframe pero me da como resultado qscrollarea.

Qué puedo hacer? Por favor!!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buena tardes, gracias por contestar.
A ver, como se aprecia en el gráfico. Quiero que al hacer click sobre cualquiera de las tarjetas los QLineEdits se carguen con la información pertinente.

Comment: En mi opinión, la respuesta que te dieron a través del bot no es exactamente lo que te querían transmitir. Lo que sucede es que no estás mostrando el esfuerzo que hiciste para resolver el problema. Si querés que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, te recomiendo editar y mostrar, por ejemplo, un código donde intentes resolver lo planteado o algunos de los links visitados para ver si allí se resolvía el problema.

Comment: Gracias Dante S.! Entiendo; el problema real es que no es problema de código. Yo podría reformular la pregunta y adjuntar las mil y una línea de código que he implementado. Debo hacerlo? Porque es difícil a través de las limitaciones de los comentarios. Estoy varado en este punto... Pero si consideras que es necesario lo replanteo y adjunto el código donde creo la tarjeta y el controlador y la página que contiene el QToolBox (donde se cargan las tarjetas) y el código del controlador.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la atención. creo haber resuelto el problema, era simple, sólo que estaba atascado o varado. Pero siempre  hay una solución para todo. Era simple, en la documentación de riverbank se advierte que si se pasa un objeto como parámetro de una señal, pues esta debe ser declarada del tipo QObjetct, además en el controlador al crear el objeto tarjeta le asigné el objectName respectivo a cada tarjeta y ahi mismo enlacé la señal con el slot del tipo pyqtslot, era todo. Mil gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

La repuesta era simple, sólo que hay que ir más allá... Después de tanto darle vuelta al asunto la solución fue la siguiente:

En la declaración de la señal en la tarjeta:

```
 prodClicked = pyqtSignal(Producto)
```

o bien

```
prodClicked = pyqtSignal(Producto, "prodClicked")
```

Ya en el controlador fue necesario lo siguiente: primero generar un método o ranura del tipo pyqtslot como se observa

```
@pyqtSlot(Producto)
def load_item(self, p:Producto):
    self.ui.txtInvoiceDetail.setText(p.Nombre)
    self.ui.txtInvoiceUnitPrice.setText(p.Precio)
    self.ui.txtInvoiceProdCode.settext(p.Codigo)
```

Y al instanciar la tarjeta se realizó de la siguiente manera:

```
for xp in range(cant):
    xItem=self.lista_conos[xp]
    cono = TopCone(xItem)
    cono.setObjectName(f"cono_{xp}")
    cono.prodClicked.connect(self.load_item)
    self.ui.layout_conos.addWidget(cono,pos[xp].x, pos[xp].y)
```